# Adjusting Image Placement and Scaling in LaTeX to Fill the Gap

Tags: graphics

I am facing an issue in LaTeX regarding the placement and scaling of an image. I have a LaTeX document where I included an image using the figure environment. However, when I modify the scale of the image to fit it within the available space, the image gets pushed to the next page.

Here is the code snippet I am using to include the image:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Images/Chapitre 3/Sprint 3/Sprint 3 UC.png}
    \caption{Diagramme de cas d'utilisation détaillé de sprint 3}
    \label{fig:sprint3-use-case}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

As you can see, the issue with width=0.6, is that the image is too small leaving so much gap below it, if i adjust it by modifying the width and making it width=0.7, it goes to the next page.
[image]

I've tried using scale and it displayed the same issue and i tried to remove [hbt!] and nothing has changed.What I want to achieve is to adjust the image placement and fill the remaining space the image. I need guidance on how to adjust the image scale to make it bigger.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. That happens, because `figure` is a floating environment. Latex will place it where it produces the best typesetting result and not exactly where you've written the code. There are options to force the placement of an image (many helpful possibilities can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text), for instance), but i wouldn't recommend it. First finish the section and let Latex do the placement. Of course, just my personal opinion ;) In a hurry, you could try to place the image without the `figure` environment.

Comment: that's why there is a label: so that you can write "dans la figure~\ref{fig:sprint3-use-case}~page~\pageref{fig:sprint3-use-case}". Then it doesn't matter where the figure is. You can also use the varioref package which changes the text depending on if the figure is on the same page or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forced the float to be placed using H specifier.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Images/Chapitre 3/Sprint 3/Sprint 3 UC.png}
  \caption{Diagramme de cas d'utilisation détaillé du sprint 3}
  \label{fig:Sprint3_UC}
\end{figure}
```